# Choosing the pivot for the rotation matrix in similarity transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix

I have arrived at an equation in the *similarity transformation* -

$M_r$ = $T. M_{r-1}. T^t$ ,where $T$ is the rotation matrix and $M_r$ ,$M_{r-1}$ are similar matrices. My aim is to find the rotation matrix $T$ with a pivot element $(a,b)$ such that all elements $m_{ij} \in M$ will be as follows :

$m_{ij} \neq 0$ , if $|i-j| = 1$

$m_{ij} \neq 0$ , if $i=j$ , i.e, it lies on the principal diagonal

I found the similarity transformation of a matrix in an application for Microwave filter design by *[Richard J. Cameron](https://doi.org/10.1109/22.754877)*, "General coupling matrix synthesis methods for Chebyshev filtering functions" where they used *similarity transformation* using rotation matrix for annihilation of elements. But the concept of **setting the pivot** is not very clear to me.

Can someone explain how the pivot is set to eliminate a particular element of $M$, for instance?

Comment: Is $M_0$ symmetric?

Comment: Anyway, at a quick glance this looks like a variant of tridiagonal reduction (see e.g. [Golub, Van Loan, IV edition, Sec. 8.3.1]), only that Givens transformations are used instead of Householder ones.

Comment: Yes $M_0$ is symmetric.

Comment: And there must be something wrong in your formulas: the first requirement tells you $m_{11}=0$, the third one $m_{11}\neq 0$.

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited.